# Align text to the middle of it's box border

Tags: css

Is it possible to align a dynamic text to the middle of it's left side box?

The initial display of the elements without CSS looks like this as all the elements are align to the same border:

```
       Text
       |
       Another text
```

But Im trying to achieve this effect:

```
      Text
       |
  Another text
```

I don't know how to explain it properly so I have created a JSFiddle to show it: https://jsfiddle.net/pkpy27oh/

I want to center the text over and below the div with the border. The negative margin can be adjusted when you know the space that its going to take a static string but with dynamical strings it's not something that can be done with predefined negative margins. I'm trying to do it just using CSS, without JavaScript.

I have tried to establish a maximum width, align the text in the middle into its container and then set a negative margin to the half of that maximum width but I wonder if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: I'm confused. Maybe this doesn't make a lot of sense or maybe I'm missing something? What's wrong with `text-align:center`?

Comment: @Albzi `text-align:center;` won't center his `<div style="border-left: 1px solid #000;">&nbsp;</div>` because it has no text and is block not inline or inline-block. But if he did make the border div inline-block then it would be center

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/pkpy27oh/10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use display: inline-block and text-align: center:

[Example Updated](https://jsfiddle.net/pkpy27oh/9/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inline-block">
    <div>Text</div>
    <div style="border-left: 1px solid #000; display: inline-block;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div>Longer text</div>
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  margin: 10px 50px;
  text-align: left;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an odd requirement for sure.  If `transform:translateX` is acceptable for your requirements you could try this:

```css
.container {
  margin: 10px 50px;
}

.offset {
  display:inline-block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
Problem:

<div class="container">
  <div class="offset">Text</div>
  <div style="border-left: 1px solid #000;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="offset">Longer text</div>
</div>

Expected result:

<div class="container">
  <div style="margin-left: -15px">Text</div>
  <div style="border-left: 1px solid #000;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="margin-left: -35px">Longer text</div>
</div>
```

The `display:inline-block` collapses the element down to its shortest width and `transform:translateX(-50%)`  offsets it by half of its width.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to center the items in your container and give the div with the border a width of 1px.

```
<div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
  <div>Text</div>
  <div style="border-left: 1px solid #000; width: 1px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div>Longer text</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pkpy27oh/8/